# Combinatorial bijection on monotone sequences

Tags: co.combinatorics, permutations, symmetric-groups, enumerative-combinatorics, algebraic-combinatorics

Let $(n),\mu$ be the partition of $n$  define $H_g^{m}((n);\mu)$ count's the number of tuples $(\tau_1,\ldots,\tau_r)$ of transposition in symmetric group $S_n$ with the following conditions

$$ (1,2,\ldots,n)\tau_1\ldots \tau_r =\mu$$

$\tau_i$ are transposition written as $(a_i , b_i)$ and $a_i <b_i$ such that 
 $$ b_1\leq b_2\leq\ldots \leq b_r. $$
$$r=2g-1+\text{len}(\mu) $$
 A result in the paper that is Theorem 2 states 
https://arxiv.org/pdf/1005.0151.pdf
state that when $\mu= 1^n$ then 
$$H_g^m((12..n), 1^n )= Cat_{n-1}T(n+g-1,n-1).....(**) $$
Notice in this particular case $r=2g-1+n$.

I have the following expression the numbers which are called central factorial numbers
$$T(a,b)= 2 \sum_{j={0}}^{b}(-1)^{b-j} \frac{j^{2a}}{(b-j)!(b+j)!}$$
where $Cat_n$ dentoe the catalan number. 
Even the paper gives a combinatorial description of $T(a,b)$. 
$T(a,b)$ has the following combinatorial description. It is the number of ways to put $\{1,2,\ldots a, 1^{'} , \ldots , a^{'}\}$ in $b$ non empty disjoint box such that if $i$ be the least integer in the box then $i^{'}$ belong the box as well. 
$Cat_{n-1}$ has the combinatorial description of writing $(1,2\ldots,n)$ cycle as monotonic $(n-1)$ tuples of transposition.

My question is if there exists a combinatorial bijection? That is given a the seq in LHS of (**) I would construct an element belong to $Cat_{n-1}$ and $T(n-1+g,n-1)$ ?

I am also placing an example in the case $n=3, g=1$

The LHS set is given as follows 
$$[[(2,3),(2,3),(2,3),(1,3)],[(2,3),(1,3),(2,3),(2,3)],[(2,3),(1,3),(1,3),(1,3)],[(1,3),(2,3),(1,3),(2,
3)],[(1,3),(1,3),(2,3),(1,3)],[(1,2),(2,3),(2,3),(2,3)],[(1,2),(2,3),(1,3),(1,3)],[(1,2),(1,3),(1,3),
(2,3)],[(1,2),(1,2),(2,3),(1,3)],[(1,2),(1,2),(1,2),(2,3)]]
 $$
The above gives a set of 10 tuple of length 4 each. it monotonic

Now $$Cat_2 =2$$ and $T(3,2)=5$ The elements of $Cat_2$ can be given as follows 2 cyles 
$$[[(2,3),(1,3)],[(1,2),(2,3)]]$$ 
I have no idea how to construct the set $T(3,2)$ to make an combinatorial bijection?

Comment: This looks like an interesting question, but it is extremely hard to read currently.  Maybe you could polish it a little bit.  For a start: you introduce $\nu$ in the very first line, but it seems it is unused.  Also, "Let define $H^m_g((n); \mu)$  count the number of tuples $(\tau_1,\dots \tau_r)$ in symmetric group $S_n$." doesn't make sense on its own.  I guess the description in the paragraph that follows explains what it means, but you should say so.  Also, $\mu$ doesn't appear.

Comment: It would also help if you could cite the equation in the paper, because apparently your notation is different.

Comment: (It's Theorem~2 in the paper.)

Comment: I made some edits. I extremely sorry about the bad write up initially. I tried to fix it. Yes it's Theorem 2